# split long hex numbers by 0D 0A in R

Tags: r, split, carriage-return

I want to write a code in R to split hex numbers by delimiters. I have a file including with all hex numbers separated by space like below:

```
0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x0d 0x0a 0x05 0x06 0x07 0x0d 0x0a
```

I want to split all of these hex numbers by 0x0d (CR:carriage return) and 0x0a (LF: line feed), i mean i want output like this:

```
0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 
0x05 0x06 0x07
```

I think i can use functions like strsplit() but i dont know how. Would you please tell me how can i implement this in R?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would a pair of `gsub` calls work?

```
text <- "0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x0d 0x0a 0x05 0x06 0x07 0x0d 0x0a"
text <- gsub( "0x0d", "\r", text )
text <- gsub( "0x0a", "\n", text )
```

Which gives:

```
text
[1] "0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 \r \n 0x05 0x06 0x07 \r \n"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(purrr)
library(stringi)
library(magrittr)

# stringi & tidyverse
readLines(textConnection("0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x0d 0x0a 0x05 0x06 0x07 0x0d 0x0a")) %>%
  stri_split_fixed("0x0d 0x0a") %>%
  .[[1]] %>%
  stri_trim_both() %>%
  discard(equals, "")
## [1] "0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04" "0x05 0x06 0x07"

# base R + a little tidyverse
readLines(textConnection("0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x0d 0x0a 0x05 0x06 0x07 0x0d 0x0a")) %>%
  strsplit("0x0d 0x0a") %>%
  .[[1]] %>%
  trimws() %>%
  discard(equals, "")
## [1] "0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04" "0x05 0x06 0x07"

# old school R
con <- textConnection("0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x0d 0x0a 0x05 0x06 0x07 0x0d 0x0a")
lines <- readLines(con)
lines <- strsplit(lines, "0x0d 0x0a")[[1]]
lines <- trimws(lines)
lines <- lines[lines != ""]
lines
## [1] "0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04" "0x05 0x06 0x07"
```

`paste0()` to make a single string with line breaks. `cat()` to display to the screen or write to a file as separate lines.